# Invalid form for an assignment in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I can't get this code to compile uding either the g77 minGW compiler or the g95 compiler.  Does anyone know why?

---

I get these errors with the g77:

diff5z10.for: In subroutine `diffract':

diff5z10.for:579:

```
    Tropo100 = 20.34 - .077 * Dist
             ^
```

Invalid form for assignment statement at (^)

diff5z10.for:581:

```
    IF (Freq .GT. 1000)  FreqAdj = 24.5 - 7200/(Freq+3000)
     ^
```

Invalid form for assignment statement at (^)

---

and i get these errors when compiling with g95:

In file diff5z10.for:574

```
  CLUTTER = steep*CLUTTER
  1
```

Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
In file diff5z10.for:580

```
  FreqAdj = 23.978 - 58026.76 / (Freq + 2320)
  1
```

Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)

---

here is the code from this section of the program:
(starting with line 362)

```
   Span = .28 - .144 * (Round - 1.2)
   Para = C / Span**2
  IF (Ratio .GT. .4) Para = 6.25 * (C - 1)
  CLUTTER = Para * (RATIO - .4)**2 - C  
  IF (CLUTTER .GT. 0.) CLUTTER = 0.


  CSlope =  SQRT(freq)/350
  steep = 1 + CSlope * (dist - Horizon)
  IF (steep .LT. 0) steep = 0
  IF (steep .GT. 1) steep = 1
  CLUTTER = steep*CLUTTER



 Tropo100 = 20.34 - .077 * Dist
 FreqAdj = 23.978 - 58026.76 / (Freq + 2320)
 IF (Freq .GT. 1000)  FreqAdj = 24.5 - 7200/(Freq+3000)
 TropoFd = Tropo100 - FreqAdj

  FS_field = 106.9 - 20 * LOG10(Dist)     
  Scatter = TropoFd - FS_field         !loss ref to free space
  DiffL = Scatter  -  DLOSS
   Combine = 150/(20 - DiffL) - 5
  IF (DiffL .LT. -10) Combine = 0
  IF (DiffL .GT. 10)  Combine = DiffL
  DLOSS = DLOSS + Combine

  RETURN
  END
```

Comment: Have you declared the variables (and are you using `IMPLICIT NONE`) in the code?  If so, what is the type of `Tropo100`, `Dist`, etc.?  Also, are you sure that free-form source is enabled when compiling with g77?

Comment: @Tim Whitcomb - he doesn't have to declare the variables, as long as he's doing it neatly. Good grief, yes, I know it is recommended these days, but I have about 50mb of fortran code with no traces of implicit none, and it all works like swiss clocks. He should check the types though (and understand them!)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the spacing in your snippet is reflective of what's actually in the source code, your compilers might getting confused with line-continuation characters (which, in archaic FORTRAN style fall in Column 6) or line number characters (Columns 1-5).  There are a few things you could try:

- Enable free-form source in the compilation options
- Rename the file from `myfile.f` to `myfile.f90` and recompile with g95

As always, when dealing with older-style code, the standard warnings such as "Always use `implicit none` also apply.

Comment: Boy, do I miss card decks for coding. Wait...no I don't.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your indentation style? Sometimes your compiler will treat tabs in a badway, not knowing with how many spaces to replace them. It will then output seemingly random errors, because it doesn't understand where the line header is.